# MeshFunction at azimuthal angles for RegionPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

> **Edit**: I said "polar angle"... It should be "Azimuthal angle". Sorry.

I want to plot a mesh line at a certain *azimuthal* angle in `RegionPlot3D`. My goal is to show the intersection of a rotating vertical plane with the surface of `RegionPlot3D`.

I tried with `ArcTan[#1,#2]&` but it doesn't work as expected. See for example:

```
SeedRandom[100];
pts = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {100, 3}];
RegionPlot3D[ConvexHullMesh[pts], 
    MeshFunctions -> {ArcTan[#1, #2] & }, Mesh -> {{-Pi/4}}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

I just want the line at `-Pi/4` (and also at `3Pi/4`), but it shows another at `Pi`. Also this method, sometimes complains about `ArcTan[0,0]`. I tried with `Arg[#1+#2*I]&` but got the same result.

Comment: Did you try `ArcTan[Sqrt[#1^2 + #2^2], #3]`?

Comment: @Coolwater, that might work, but we'll need OP to clarify what he meant by "polar angle". Ivan: This is spherical coordinates we're discussing, yes?

Comment: @J.M. Sorry, I don't know if it's called "polar angle" but I mean the angle in the xy pane (Azimuth?).

Comment: @Coolwater sorry, I meant Azimuthal angle.

Comment: Try using the equation of the azimuthal plane: `MeshFunctions -> {Det[{{#1, #2}, {Cos[t], Sin[t]}}] &}, Mesh -> {{0}}`, where `t` is the azimuthal angle you want.

Comment: @Rahul I wish I had seen your comment...very nice...would have learned a lot as well as not wasting time on a silly 'tangent' (pun intended)...avoids all the issues with `Tan`

Comment: @Rahul Very nice! Works great for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This serves to preserve [@Rahul](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/484/rahul)'s excellent answer that was [provided in a comment to the question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86221/meshfunction-at-azimuthal-angles-for-regionplot3d#comment235041_86221). Rahul suggested to use the equation of the azimuthal plane directly: assuming that $t$ is the azimuthal angle you want to highlight, then:

```
MeshFunctions -> {Det[{{#1, #2}, {Cos[t], Sin[t]}}] &}, Mesh -> {{0}}
```

In context, this turns into the following:

```
SeedRandom[100];
pts = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {100, 3}];

Manipulate[
  RegionPlot3D[
    ConvexHullMesh[pts],
    MeshFunctions -> {Det[{{#1, #2}, {Cos[t], Sin[t]}}] &},
    Mesh -> {{0}},
    MeshStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.01], Red],
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.6]],
    Axes -> True
  ],
  {{t, Pi/3}, 0, Pi}
]
```

[image: static example of output]